# Sort numbers by absolute value in tcsh

Tags: shell

In tcsh, I have an array

```
set value = "-4.13 3.62 3.40 3.83 3.53 3.49 3.53 3.64 3.31 3.34 3.55 3.99 3.42 3.47 3.54 3.35 3.40 3.41 3.37 3.96 3.44 3.66 3.51 3.33 3.50 3.48 -3.38 -3.33 -3.61 -3.37 -3.92 -4.27 -3.32"
```

with numbers. I want to sort them by the absolute values. I did the following script, it works sometimes, but not for this particular array.

```
perl -e 'print join " ", sort { abs($b) <=> abs($a) } split(" ", $ARGV[0]);' "$value"
```

returns message like

*Unrecognized switch: -4.13 3.62 3.40 3.83 3.53 3.49 3.53 3.64 3.31 3.34 3.55 3.99 3.42 3.47 3.54 3.35 3.40 3.41 3.37 3.96 3.44 3.66 3.51 3.33 3.50 3.48 -3.38 -3.33 -3.61 -3.37 -3.92 -4.27 -3.32  (-h will show valid options)*.

Then `value_abs` is empty. Could you please help to fix this issue? I am also not sure if the for loop for sorting is a good idea, is there any better solution?

```
set value_abs = `perl -e 'print join " ", sort { abs($b) <=> abs($a) } split(" ", $ARGV[0]);' "$value"`

set sorted_indices = ()

foreach element ( $value_abs )
    set index = `echo "$value:q" | tr ' ' '\n' | awk -v el="$element" '{if ($1 == el) print NR}'`
    set sorted_indices = ( $sorted_indices $index )
end
```

Comment: You could put the data in a file instead, to save yourself from headaches with shell interpolation.

Answer (score 5):

You need to tell Perl that the first number is not a switch. Use `--`:

```
perl -e 'print join " ", sort { abs($b) <=> abs($a) } split(" ", $ARGV[0]);' -- "$value"
```

Refer to [Command switches in perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#Command-Switches)

Comment: It's not just perl. In general, most unix commands that accept switches are going to have the same problem.

Comment: @briandfoy: And for most of them, this solution is going to work, too.

Answer (score 1):

In general, unix commands that take switches will see arguments that begin with a `-` as a switch. Most times, you can use the special switch `--` to tell the command to stop processing switches and use the rest as literal values.

```
some_command -x -y -z -- -literal_argument
```

Your current situation works "sometimes" because the value doesn't always start with a `-`.

So, in general, when you want to start the literal values part of a unix command you are constructing in parts for data that you don't know about ahead of time, throw the `--` in there. This keeps people from sneaking unintended switches in there too.

As for a better solution, once you have perl involved, you shouldn't need the rest of it. However, you don't show what you want for the output

---

In your comment, you mention that you really want the sequence numbers sorted by the value. That's pretty easy in perl with a Schwartzian Transform. In short, you make an array reference per element, sort on the generated key, and then undo it. In this case, the last map (the first one that works) goes through the indices of `@ARGV` and makes a two-element array ref with index and the absolute value of the item. The `sort` uses the thing in index one to sort the array refs. The final `map` extracts the index again:

```
$ perl -le 'print join " ", 
   map { $_->[0] } sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
   map { [ $_, abs($ARGV[$_]) ] } 0 .. $#ARGV
   ' -- -4 5 3 -2 9
3 2 0 1 4
```

That `3 2 0 1 4` in the output correspond to the elements -2 3 -4 5 9.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. The rest of the code is just getting the index order after sorting. I have several arrays of the same length as ```value```, and their elements are all paired. I want to sort all of these arrays according to the absolute value of ```value```. To do so, ```sorted_indices``` will be applied to other arrays.